# How to get value input form from FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, mean

Good day, guys I'd like to find the solution to solve my problem. I have a **FormGroup** like this :

```
  profileForm  = new FormGroup({ 
    username   : new FormControl(),
    firstname  : new FormControl(),
    lastname   : new FormControl(),
    email      : new FormControl(),
    password   : new FormControl(),
  });
```

And I'd like to get the value by using :

```
const user = {
  firstname : this.profileForm.get('firstname').value,
  lastname  : this.profileForm.get('lastname').value,
  username  : this.profileForm.get('username').value,
  email     : this.profileForm.get('email').value,
  password  : this.profileForm.get('password').value
}
console.log(user)
```

But I got null value for each input form. But the value exists in the HTML form input :

```
<input name="username" matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" [readonly]="true" value="{{details?.data.username}}" >
```

Help me to fix this, thank you.

Comment: 1. Is there a submit button after which you want to retrieve these values from the template? 2. What is details here `value="{{details?.data.username}}"`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you need'nt use value={...}, **remove it!** you has yet formControlName. I suppose you has the input enclose in a `<form [formGroup ]="profileForm ">` and you has the full value in profileForm.value or profileForm.getRawValue()

Answer (score 1):

I think `value="{{details?.data.username}}"` is not binding value back to you. It just prints the value in dom.

I assume you getting data `details?.data.username` in `ngOnInit()` ( or may be somewhere else) from there you can bind to your form like this

```
this.profileForm.get('firstname').setValue(details?.data.username)
```

and remove this `value="{{details?.data.username}}"` from html.

Comment: Yes, I getting data from `details?.data.username` from `ngOnInit()` I tried to remove the value in the HTML form and change the .ts file as you suggest, but it give me error `Property 'username' does not exist on type '(data: any) => any'.ts(2339)`

Comment: try `details?.data["username"]` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is that you access the Formgroup (which is basically an object which contains all formControls), which don't contain the value. You should be access controls of the Form group.
An example:

```
this.profileForm.controls.username.value
```

Comment: No, Nico, not use fom.controls.username.value, use form.get('username').value or form.value.username <--this one not use in a validator

Comment: I know both options, too. But why are these ones recommend?

Comment: nobody sure you that Angular team not change the "form object". Imagine that they need put the controls in an array "othersControls" to make an improve (well I'm sure that they are not thinking in this idea). They, for compatibility, will change the method "get" to take account this change. All Angular aplications that was using "controls" can not upgrade the new version of Angular, all the applications that was using the method get can upgrade without problems.